# How to extend multiple classes in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I extend multiple classes like this:

```
class Backend_api extends CI_Controller, Appointments
{
        do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, multiple inheritance is not allowed in php, but if you need to access functions in the Appointments class, why not just create an instance of it in the class and call the function on that instance?

```
$ins = new Appointments();
$result = $ins->someFunction();
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not support multiple inheritance

Comment: Uhm, this is a problem for me 'cause I need to use some method of CI_Controller and also use a function available in the Appointments class from the Backend_api class..

Comment: Try to agregate needed objects

Comment: how can I achieve this?

Comment: For example, in constructor: `$this->object1 = new Class1;`, `$this->object2 = new Class2;`, something like this. and use this objects in methods of your object. `$this->object1->method1();`

Comment: There should be no problems due to the fact that the class is located in the Appointments appointment.php file and then try to access another file? Thanks+

Comment: Yes, classes may be in different files. And it is preffer way to declare classes in different files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96073/discussion-between-dillinger-and-mnv).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, PHP does not support multiple inheritance.
But since PHP5.4 you can use **traits** and use them in your classes. More info about traits [here](http://php.net/trait)

Comment: traits? What do you mean? I just want call a function of Appointments class from the Backend_api class that's it..

Comment: If you want to call a function of one class `Class1` from another class `Class2` - just pass object of `Class1` to `Class2` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Appointments class you could extends from CI_Controller like this

```
class Appointments extends CI_Controller
{
        //stuff...
}
```

Now you can extends from Appointments cause it's already extends from CI_Controller.

```
class Backend_api extends Appointments
{
        //do stuff...
}
```